# Why the content of this paragraph appear under the header tag content?

Tags: html, css, header

Into a simple HTML\CSS on which I am working on (written by another developer) I have found this situation, in the HTML section I have an `header` tag and under this header is declared a paragraph `<p>`:

```
<header id="headerBar">
  HEADER CONTENT
</header>

<p>HELLO WORLD !!!</p>
```

And this is the related CSS:

```
#headerBar {
    background-color: #2ba981;
    color: white;
    height: 80px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

Here you can see the related JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/AndreaNobili/h4xw4pva/1/

As you can see in the JSFiddle, applying the previous CSS setting, the `<p>` content is displayed under the `<header>`.

Why I obtain this behavior? What is the cause? What is wrong?

Comment: more info about how fixed elements are placed  https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_absolute_and_fixed_positioning#Fixed_positioning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the fixed position header is now taken out of the document flow and so the paragraph is hidden behind it.

The solution is to add top padding to the `body` equal to the `header` height.

```css
#headerBar {
  background-color: #2ba981;
  color: white;
  height: 80px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
}
body {
  padding-top: 80px;
}
```

```html
<header id="headerBar">
  HEADER CONTENT
</header>

<p>HELLO WORLD !!!</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the header `height` as `padding-top` of body. You should learn about first  `position:fixed` [here](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/).

```
body{
  padding-top: 80px; /* its header height */
}
```

updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/AndreaNobili/h4xw4pva/1/

Answer (score 1):

For `#headerBar` position is setted as `position:fixed` . If you set it as `position: relative` means the paragraph will not hide.

Kindly visit below links to understand position property:

1) http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

2) http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_position&preval=fixed

Answer (score 1):

because of the position:fixed; property. You are also using z-index which also shows content above of each element.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening so, because the in CSS `position: fixed;` has been applied to the `header` element. With position as `fixed`, the block level elements remain unmoved in the page, so that one has the access to the things defined in the fixed section. 
To solve, one should either removed the `fixed property` or give some `margin-bottom` greater than the height of the `fixed block` element.